# Printer connected with Ubuntu 14.04 and rest of the system are running windows

Tags: 14.04, windows, printing, samba, windows-10

I have Ubuntu 14.04, windows 10 & 7. My printer is connected with Ubuntu 14.04 and I can take print from it. All devices are on same network. I just want the windows systems to access printer connected with Ubuntu.

Unfortunately I am unable to find the samba settings in Ubuntu because my printer's system settings is looking different.

[image: Snapshot of Printer Settings]

Can anyone help me with step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

On the server machine (the one the printer is attached to), 
open `System -> Administration -> Printing` (If the menu item does not exist you need to add system-config-printer to the menu). . This will open the Printer Configuration window.

Select Server in the menu bar, and then Settings. This will open the Basic Server Settings window.
Check the second box:

Publish shared printers connected to this server If this computer acts as both a Print Server and a client (it does need access to a printer connected to another computer), select also the first box, `"Show printers shared by other systems"`

Right click the printer and check the Shared option, if not checked yet

Check that users that you want to be able to use the printer are not excluded. See `Properties>Access Control`. The default settings may be set to `"deny printing for everyone except ..."`

But you might want to `"allow printing for everyone"`.

**Ubuntu print server compatible with Windows (Samba)**

If your Ubuntu print server shall be able to work also with Windows clients, you must first make sure that the SAMBA package is installed (e.g. using Synaptic package manager). Then, do a little configuration change to SAMBA. In brief, you must uncomment the following lines in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` - open terminal and run:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

In the [printers] section:

```
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

When done, restart Samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
sudo service nmbd restart
```

Also, one would want to allow the following ports through a firewall (ufw for example) via:

```
sudo ufw allow 139/tcp  
sudo ufw allow 445/tcp  
sudo ufw allow 137/udp  
sudo ufw allow 138/udp
```